# Call Teradata Stored Procedure with output parameters from Python using callproc

Tags: python, teradata, procedure

I am running this simple python script to call a Teradata procedure but the result is not returning output parameter via Python. The procedure is working fine and returning output data from Teradata SQL editor.

```
import teradata

method,host,username,password = 'odbc','xx.xxxx.com','abcde', 'password123'

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False,logLevel="TRACE")
P1="ABC"
P2="TESTING1"

with udaExec.connect(method=method,system=host, username=username,password=password, driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10",transactionMode='Teradata') as session:

results=session.callproc('db.TEST_PYTHON_CALL_RETURN2',(P1,P2,teradata.OutParam("Output1")))
print(results)
```

**Output returned is**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32>python ./TD_CALL_SP_3.py
['ABC', 'TESTING1', '']
```

Can someone help me with this? I have tried out various options with no success yet.

Comment: How are the SP parameters defined in the DDL? Two IN (or defaulted) parameters followed by one OUT?

Comment: Yes you are right. Here is the DDL
`CREATE  PROCEDURE db.TEST_PYTHON_CALL_RETURN2  
(
IN IN_TEST_CODE CHAR(5),
IN IN_TEST_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(30),
OUT OUT_SEQUENCE VARCHAR(30))
     BEGIN
    SEL TEST_SEQUENCE INTO :OUT_SEQUENCE FROM db.TEST_SP_CALL WHERE TEST_CODE = :IN_TEST_CODE and TEST_DESCRIPTION = :IN_TEST_DESCRIPTION;
   END;`

Here is the table data:

TEST_CODE TEST_DESCRIPTION TEST_SEQUENCE
ABC   TESTING1 1

Comment: That looks OK to me. The older *teradata* package (UdaExec) might not be fully compatible with ODBC 16.xx though. You might try using the current *teradatasql* package instead (which does not depend on ODBC at all). Note that for *teradatasql* you would need to use the `execute` method rather than `callproc`.to be able to retrieve OUT parameter values.

Comment: Note that for *teradatasql* you would need to use the `execute` method with a `CALL db.TEST_PYTHON_CALL_RETURN2(?,?,?)` statement rather than `callproc`.method, to be able to retrieve OUT parameter values.